# i try do a ban command with a button to unban the banned user but idk

Tags: button, discord.py, member

i try do a ban command with a button to unban the banned user in discord.py

i tried this

```py
@client.hybrid_command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member:discord.Member, *, reason="nicht gegeben"):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    embed = discord.Embed(description=f' {member.mention} wurde gebannt von {ctx.author.mention}\n**Grund:** {reason}')
    unban = discord.ui.Button(label="UNBAN", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    view=discord.ui.View()
    view.add_item(unban)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)
    button_callback = button_callback
    async def button_callback(interaction, member):
        print(member)
        await interaction.guild.unban(member)
```

Comment: Can we see the error message if there is one? What's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0):

You should have included; what didn't work, what did work and what error you got. Anyway, here's what's wrong with your code.

1. `button_callback` is referenced before assignment.

Simply, move it up

```
    view.add_item(unban)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)
    async def button_callback(interaction, member):
        print(member)
        await interaction.guild.unban(member)
    button_callback = button_callback
```

2. You should initiate the button's callback before sending the view

```
    unban = discord.ui.Button(label="UNBAN", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    view=discord.ui.View()
    async def button_callback(interaction, member):
        print(member)
        await interaction.guild.unban(member)
    button_callback = button_callback
    view.add_item(unban)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)
```

3. Incorrect callback assignment.
   You should be assigning `button_callback` to the button itself. You can assign your callback to the [button.callback](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.Button.callback).

```
button_callback = button_callback
```

To

```
unban.callback = button_callback
```

4. `button_callback` "missing required positional argument 'member'". Since your `button_callback` is inside your command, there's no need to define member here.

```
    async def button_callback(interaction):
        print(member)
        await interaction.guild.unban(member)
```

PS: The button callback has no response so it will say "interaction failed".

You also got "error convert member". This is because the member is no longer a member (not in the server) so you should be using `discord.User`.

```
@client.hybrid_command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member:discord.User, *, reason="nicht gegeben"):
    ...
```

Comment: can you show the full command like by this code i have the error convert member